# C# Master Detail gridview on SelectionChanged

Tags: c#

I have one form with grid(dataGridView1) and textbox(txtSearch). When I type something in textbox grid filter by field acSubject. Now I put second grid and I want new Custom SQL query which will be depend on selected row in dataGridView1.

SQL would be:

```
select anUserID from the_setsubjcontact where acSubject = @acSubject
```

How can I do this?

Code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=local\s08r2;Initial Catalog=Demo;User id=sa;Password=sa";
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
            SELECT acSubject, acAddress, acPost, acName, acPhone, 
            acFieldSA, acFieldSB, acFieldSC, acFieldSD, acFieldSE, 
            anFieldNA, anFieldNB, anFieldNC, anFieldND, anFieldNE, OdgovornaOsoba, acSubjTypeBuyer
            FROM ARS.dbo._ARSCRM_vSubjekti
            ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("acSubject like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

        //User selected a cell (show the first cell in the row)
        if (dgv.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            txtAcFieldSA.Text = dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        
    }
}
```

I was success when I use DataSet from C#, but with CustomSQL I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void ShowDetails(int UserId)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=local\s08r2;Initial Catalog=Demo;User id=sa;Password=sa";
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
           select anUserID from the_setsubjcontact where acSubject = @acSubjec", con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@acSubjec, UserId.ToString());
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;

        }

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

        //User selected a cell (show the first cell in the row)
        if (dgv.SelectedCells.Count > 0 && dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex >-1 &&  dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells.Count > 0)
            txtAcFieldSA.Text = dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
ShowDetails(int.Parse(txtAcFieldSA.Text));

    }
```

Comment: ShowDetails(int.Parse(txtAcFieldSA.Text));

Here we send txtAcFieldSA.text and I want send acSubject from selected row in dataGridView1, is that possible?

Comment: I edited my response to chose from Cells[0] if your acSubject  is in the first cell.

Comment: I put this:
ShowDetails(dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

and this:
 private void ShowDetails(string Subjekt)

Now work perfect when I select row with mouse, but when I type in txtSearch I receive error:
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
On calling ShowDetails.

Comment: On which line of the code are you getting this error exactly?

Comment: On this:
ShowDetails(dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

Comment: I have fix this, first subject was '' and that was problem

Comment: It's not fixed, I forgot uncomment one row, still same error afer I have eliminated '' row

Comment: Don't do it all in one line. Separate your code into several lines because your filter will not always return a value and thus your SelectedCells and Cells arrays are 0 length.

Comment: Basically: 
if([dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex >-1) // these is something selected
{var selectedSubject = dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0]‌​.Value.ToString();
// continue here. YOu can also add more checks 
}

Comment: if(dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex >-1)
Same error I recceive on this row

Comment: Then check for dgv.SelectedCells.Length > 0 before proceeding.